# Sending email with javax.mail, works with gmail but get error with others

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I tried the code suggested on [this page](http://www.journaldev.com/2532/javamail-example-send-mail-in-java-smtp) and it worked really well with gmail, as in the example. I specifically worked with the SSL Authentication Example.

Using the same code but changing the credentials and the SMTP Host, I get the following error:

```
 javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;   nested exception
 is:    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2
 <me@MY-PC>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified
 address

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1996)
    at
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1240)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)   at
 javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)  at
 EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:49)     at
 EmailSSL.main(EmailSSL.java:56) Caused by:
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2
 <me@MY-PC>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified
 address

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1896)
    ... 5 more
```

What bugs me is that the sender's address is now my *local PC's address*, even if the one specified in the code is not.

Why would the exact same code would work with gmail and not with another host?

Thanks for reading!
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Different servers have different requirements.

This [Gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370) might be useful.

See also the [JavaMail FAQ entry for Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).